# Has anyone played more distinct roles in Star Wars than Warwick Davis?

Tags: star-wars, actors

Warwick Davis has played Wicket in *Return of the Jedi*, three bit characters in *The Phantom Menace*, and apparently another role in *The Force Awakens*.

Has any other actor played more distinct roles than Warwick? If not, who has played the 2nd highest number? (And what were their roles?)

I'd prefer to exclude voice actors from *The Clone Wars* and *Rebels*, unless that actor has also played a role in one of the 7 movies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warwick Davis takes the record for *impact* with the most multiple roles, at least according to [this page](http://www.starwars.com/news/4-actors-who-played-multiple-star-wars-roles) from StarWars.com.

But **[Temuera Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temuera_Morrison)** has appeared in more roles: not only **Jango Fett** but also **countless clone troopers**, as well as doing voice work for **Boba Fett** in the 2004 rerelease of *The Empire Strikes Back*.

Runners-up include:

- **[Rusty Goffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusty_Goffe)**, who appears in three distinct roles in Episode IV (**Kabe**, **Jawa**, and **GONK Droid**)
- (not in the 7 main films, but) **[Sam Witwer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Witwer)**, who's done voice work for **Galen Marek/Starkiller** (in the video game [*Star Wars: the Force Unleashed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Unleashed)), **The Son** (in Season 3 of [*Star Wars: the Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series))), **Darth Maul** (in Seasons 4-5 of [*Star Wars: the Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)) and also *Lego Star Wars: the Empire Strikes Out*), and **Emperor Palpatine** (in [*Star Wars: the Force Unleashed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Unleashed) and also one episode of [*Star Wars Rebels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels)).

Comment: What did Witner do voice work in? Also, Warwick has had *5* roles. (5th one isn't on the list in your link because it's from the new movie, but it's on IMBb)

Comment: Also, I don't know how I feel about Clones counting!